# Need optimisation of a query to avoid subquery evaluated twice in the query in an if else condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query which is using a sub-query twice for getting the result in If else condition as I couldn't hold the result first evaluated  in the condition. How can I optimise the query?

```
SELECT 
    IF(
        (SELECT 
                CONVERT( IFNULL(SUM(T.hours), 0) , DECIMAL (10 , 2 )) As Val
           FROM
                time_entries T
                    JOIN
                Issues IU2 ON (t.issue_id = IU2.Id)
           Where
                IU2.id = IU.Id)  <> 0,

         (SELECT 
                CONVERT( IFNULL(SUM(T.hours), 0) , DECIMAL (10 , 2 )) As Val
            FROM
                time_entries T
                    JOIN
                Issues IU2 ON (t.issue_id = IU2.Id)
            Where
                IU2.id = IU.Id),
         99    
       ) AS NotCovered
FROM
    issues IU
        Join
    custom_values CV ON (IU.project_id = CV.customized_id
        AND CV.value = '')
where
    IU.done_ratio <> 100;
```

Comment: Can you explain why your query does what it does? It's really unclear as to why you use the subquery twice.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume that it's merely *careless* that you've formatted your code misleadingly?

Comment: Anyway, if you want good answers about optimizing your query, then you should provide the details of your tables.

Comment: @John I agree query is return badly. But my purpose was not to miss lead.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Takarii As the evaluated condition result I could not hold for assigning it.

Answer (score 0):

Try calculating everything first and store it in a temp table, afterwards you can perform a IIF or CASE on the temp table.